Using install4j, is there a way to access code from a .war file in the distribution tree for use in a custom script action?
We have a Groovy/Java application packaged as a .war file in the distribution tree of an install4j v10 installer we are working on.  On one of the screens of the installer, we would like to access code from the .war file in a "run script" action (e.g., import a class from the .war file and use it in a script)...before the application is launched/installed.  Is this possible?

With a JAR file, you could just add the JAR file on the "Installer->Custom Code" step. It would not be packages twice and be available in scripts.
However, in a WAR file, classes are in the WEB-INF/classes directory, so getting them on the script class path for install4j without extracting the WAR file is not possible.
